# Poisson process. Time between two events.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that people immigrate to a territory according to a Poisson process with a
$\lambda =$ rate of 1 per day.

What is the probability that the time between the tenth and eleventh exceeds two days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches, through the Poisson and through the associated exponential.

The number of events in two days is a Poisson random variable $Y$ with parameter $2\lambda$. The probability that $Y=0$ is $e^{-2\lambda}$.

Or else the waiting time $W$ is an exponentially distributed random variable with parameter $2$. The probability that $W\gt 2$ is
$$\int_2^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t}\,dt.$$
Integrate (or remember the cdf of the exponential). We get $e^{-2\lambda}$.

Comment: 1) CDF of the exponential is 1 - e^(-λx). I found: 1 - e^(-2λ). Is there a problem?

2) Who is λ? Should It be 2 ?

Comment: We use $\lambda=1$, as in the statement of the problem. Didn't replace it by $1$ for the sake of generality.  So the cdf is $1-e^{-\lambda x}$, the probability it is greater than $x$ is therefore $1-(1-e^{-\lambda x})=e^{-\lambda x}$. Now let $x=2$.

Comment: I was thinking if it is correct because this is a Poisson PROCESS and not a Poisson distribuition.

Comment: Usually the notion of a random variable having Poisson distribution is introduced one course before the notion of Poisson process. So I was using the language of Poisson/Exponential distribution rather than the language of processes.

Comment: Do you mean Poisson distribuition and Poisson process are the same?

Comment: Could I ask you something else? The fact that the problem asks about the time between the tenth and the eleventh changes anything?

Comment: No, it changes nothing. The defining feature of the Poisson process, and its associated exponential distribution, is memorylessness.

Comment: could you help me on this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309551/arriving-of-packets-on-interval/309577 please!

Comment: The Poisson model is reasonable, $\lambda=40$ for $1$ sec, $80$ for $2$ sec.  We want probability that $20$ arrive in $1$ second **and** $10$ arrive in the next $2$ seconds. The result is $\left( e^{-40}\frac{40^{20}}{20!}\right)\left( e^{-80}\frac{80^{10}}{10!}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to say that the expected number of immigrants in two days is $2$, and then finding the probability that a Poisson-distributed random variable with expected value $2$ is $0$.  In that way, knowledge of discrete distributions yields knowledge of continuous distributions.