# Arriving of packets on interval

Tags: probability

During a certain time interval $[t_1, t_1 + 10s]$, the number of IP packets arriving at
a router is on average 40/seconds. What is the probability 20 packets arriving in the interval
$[t_1, t_1 + 1s]$ and 30 packages in the interval $[t_1, t_1 + 3s]$.

Is there some way to do it modifying λ to correspond to the first interval [t1,t1+1s] and getting that probability and after to [t1,t1+3s]? I am afraid to use this property.. Can you thing some way to do this using that approach?

Comment: According to which distribution are the packets sent? Uniform?

Comment: I think the most appropriated to this is Poisson.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a Poisson Process for the arrivals of packets, the arrival rate $\lambda =40$ packets per seconds. We need to compute $P(X(1)=20, X(3)=30)$. The way to compute this is to use the independent increments property of Poisson and $P [X(t + s) − X(s) = k] = (λt)^k e^{−λt}/k!$

So, 
$\\P [X(1) = 20, X(3) = 30] \\=P [X(1) − X(0) = 20, X(3) − X(1) = 10]\\= P [X(1) − X(0) = 20] P [X(3) − X(1) = 10]$

Can you calculate now?

Comment: This is the only way to do? I mean using the independent increments property?

Comment: @Richard Any other ideas on how you would solve it if arrivals are Poisson?

Comment: Is there some way to do it modifying λ to correspond to the first interval [t1,t1+1s] and getting that probability and after to [t1,t1+3s]? I am afraid to use this property.. Can you thing some way to do this using that approach?

Comment: why afraid? is it because you are not familiar with it?

Comment: Yes, I am not. Therefore I am trying to solve this withou this property. Any other ideia?

Comment: Another question: P[X(1)−X(0)=20]P[X(3)−X(1)=10]


Why not?


P[X(1)−X(0)=20]P[X(3)−X(0)=10]

Comment: @Richard You should look at your question carefully and realize that you would actually want $P[X(3)-X(1)]$

Comment: I am not so sure of that.

Comment: If I want to know the probability 20 packages arriving on [t1, t1+2s] and 30 packages arriving on [t1,t1+3s]...

P(X(2)-X(0)=20,X(3)-X(2)=30) ??