# Probability of Poisson event at time t vs. probability of event by time t

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I am modeling three events A, B, and C as Poisson processes with rates $\lambda_A$, $\lambda_B$, and $\lambda_C$ and I would like to calculate the likelihood of observing some data given my model.

A distinction that I have come across is the difference between an event happening at a specific time $t$, $P\left(T\left(E\right) = t \right)$, versus by time $t$, $P\left(T\left(E\right) \leq t \right)$, where $T\left(E\right) = E_n - E_{n-1}$ refers to the inter-arrival time between two consecutive occurrences of the event. For a single event with rate $\lambda$, the probability of these scenarios are the exponential likelihood function

$P\left(T\left(E\right) = t \right) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$

and an integration over it

$P\left(T\left(E\right) \leq t \right) = \int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda \tau} \, \textrm{d}\tau = 1 - e^{-\lambda t}$

of the exponential distribution, respectively.

It follows that the odds of the event not occurring by $t$ is

$P\left(T\left(E\right)\gt t\right) = 1 - \left(1 - e^{-\lambda t}\right) = e^{-\lambda t}$.

Returning to my three-event model, the probability of observing event A at time $t$ but not events B nor C by that time is

$P\left(T\left(A\right) = t \cap T\left(B\right) \gt t \cap T\left(C\right) \gt t \right) = \lambda_A e^{-\lambda_A t} e^{-\lambda_B t} e^{-\lambda_C t} = \lambda_A e^{-\lambda t}$

where $\lambda = \lambda_A + \lambda_B + \lambda_C$, the overall rate of events.

However, I see two non-equivalent approaches to calculate the probability of observing event A by time $t$ but not events B nor C by that time, $P\left(T\left(A\right) \leq t \cap T\left(B\right) \gt t \cap T\left(C\right) \gt t \right)$.

The first method I see is to explicitly evaluate each expression, as I did previously; that is,

$P\left(T\left(A\right) \leq t \cap T\left(B\right) \gt t \cap T\left(C\right) \gt t \right) = \left(1 - e^{-\lambda_A t}\right) e^{-\lambda_B t} e^{-\lambda_C t} = e^{-(\lambda-\lambda_A)t} - e^{-\lambda t}$.

The second is to integrate over all possible times:

$P\left(T\left(A\right) \leq t \cap T\left(B\right) \gt t \cap T\left(C\right) \gt t \right) = \int_0^t \lambda_A e^{-\lambda \tau} \, \textrm{d}\tau = \frac{\lambda_A - \lambda_A e^{-\lambda t}}{\lambda}$.

Both approaches seem equally valid to me. Which calculation should I be using, if either, and why? Thanks in advance for your help; I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the penultimate expression is correct:

$P\left(T\left(A\right) \leq t \cap T\left(B\right) \gt t \cap T\left(C\right) \gt t \right) = \left(1 - e^{-\lambda_A t}\right) e^{-\lambda_B t} e^{-\lambda_C t} = e^{-(\lambda-\lambda_A)t} - e^{-\lambda t}$.

For more info, see [an excellent answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67600/likelihood-of-multiple-event-times-modeled-as-independent-poisson-processes) to this question by [@whuber](http://stackexchange.com/users/449752/whuber) on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I can't see how the random variable $T(E)$ has $P(T(E)=t)$ non-zero, assuming continues time.

The first method I see nothing wrong with assuming these events are independent. Are they?

I can't see how you got the integral for the second method.

Comment: Another way to consider $P\left(T\left(E\right)=t\right)$ is, what is the probability that $t$ time passes between $E_{n-1}$ and $E_n$? Because the inter-arrival times in a Poisson process are exponentially distributed, this is equivalent to the value of the exponential pdf at $t$.

Comment: Yes, the events are independent. The integral in the second method mimics previous calculations. For a single event, we know $P\left(T\left(E\right)=t\right)$, so to find the probability of that event occurring over a period of time we integrate over $t$, $\int_0^tP\left(T\left(E\right)=\tau\right)\,\textrm{d}\tau = 1 - e^{-\lambda t}$. I do the same thing; I know $P\left(T\left(A\right)=t\cap T\left(B\right)\gt t \cap T\left(C\right)\gt t\right)$, so I integrate over all possible times it could occur. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306416) for an single-event example.

Comment: If $T(E)$ is continues in $t$ then $P(T(E)=t)=\int_t^t\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx=0$. For the second method you would need some joint probability distribution, which would reduce to the first method assuming independence.

Comment: Yes, the probability of the event happening in the interval $\left(t,t\right]$ is $0$ (and equivalent to the interval $\left(0,0\right]$ because the inter-arrival times are i.i.d.), but I want to calculate the probability that an inter-arrival time is $t$. Let me clarify my notation: I am interested in the $P\left(T\left(E_n\right)-T\left(E_{n-1}\right)=t\right)$, which is the exponential pdf. Regarding the second method, can you expand on why I would need a join probability distribution and how that would reduce to the first method?

Comment: If you have random variables $X$ and $Y$, then $P(X\in A)=\int_A f_X(x)dx$ and similarly $P(Y\in B)=\int_B f_Y(y)dy$. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $P(X\in A \cap Y\in B)=\int_A f_X(x)dx\int_B f_Y(y)dy$, if not then $P(X\in A \cap Y\in B)=\int_A \int_B  f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx$, where $f_{X,Y}$ is the joint probability distribution.

Comment: I'm presuming $T(E_n)−T(E_{n−1})$ is a random variable which takes values in $\mathbb R^+$. Then let $X=T(E_n)−T(E_{n−1})$ and $A=(t,t]$, and we get $P(X\in A)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, Gummi, I understand now. But then what is the significance of the pdf if $P(T(E)=t)=0$? I know that to simulate a Poisson process you draw inter-arrival times from an exponential distribution to determine the event times. I would assume that one would calculate the probability of observing some inter-arrival times under a Poisson model in a similar fashion, which is what I do above. The likelihood of observing some data under a model is equal to the probability of simulating that data under the model, no? $P(T(E)=t)$ should equal the probability of drawing $t$.

Comment: There is an infinite number of points between $t$ and $t+\epsilon$, so the probability that you get exactly $t$ is zero. However, $P(T(E)\in (t,t+\epsilon])\approx \epsilon\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$. You use the pdf (continues distribution) to calculate probabilities for some intervals, not at a single point.

Comment: Okay, so the pdf of a continuous distribution is not necessarily useful by itself, but rather in the context of an interval. So then how should I go about calculating the likelihood of observing some data (that is, an event happening at a specific time) under a Poisson model? Thanks again for all your help and patience.

Comment: It's just zero, $P(\text{something happens at exactly } t)=0$. If you really want to know if something happens around $t$ you could use $P(\text{something happens in } [t\pm\Delta t])$.

Comment: What about the exponential likelihood function described [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Maximum_likelihood)? $P\left(\lambda|X\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda e^{-\lambda x_i}$, which equates to what I describe above. Is there a particular reason that I should not use this to calculate the likelihood of the model for my data? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's not the same as probability. The likelihood is used to estimate parameters like $\lambda$ from measurements, the maximum in this case being $\lambda=1/\bar x$ (the most likely given the data).

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function and the continues case. "The actual value of a likelihood function bears no meaning. Its use lies in comparing one value with another."

Comment: Right! I want to estimate my parameters $\lambda_A$, $\lambda_B$, and $\lambda_C$. I want to calculate the likelihood of the parameters, $L\left(\lambda_A,\lambda_B,\lambda_C|D\right) = P\left(D|\lambda_A,\lambda_B,\lambda_C\right)$ (as I explained in my first sentence). In some cases, my data happens to be the specific time at which an event occurred, so I am looking for $P\left(T\left(E\right)=t|\lambda\right)$. So it looks like I am doing the right thing; I did not have any intentions of using the probability for anything else. (I apologize, though, if my terminology was unclear.)